# Capture dynamic column headers and copy the cell content in repeating rows in another sheet

Tags: vba

1. In WO_formatted2, i have Col C.Value = WO-1, WO-9 etc. that has matching data in WO_dump2(master data).
   Some col headers in WO_dump2 are dynamically added, dumped from an application with user inputs -

   > estimate.estimateTableRowList.0.skillSet.skillSetId,
   >      estimate.estimateTableRowList.0.totalEffort
   >      estimate.estimateTableRowList.0.comment.. other similar cols with index 0.

   and

   > estimate.estimateTableRowList.1.skillSet.skillSetId,
   >      estimate.estimateTableRowList.1.totalEffort
   >      estimate.estimateTableRowList.1.comment.. other similar cols with 
   >   index 1.

This continues as long as there is col data in the WO_dump2 sheet for a specific WO-1 or WO-9.

2. There is a fixed col for every dynamic col set -

   > estimate.projOsTotEffort.
3. There is also a calculated field in every dynamic col set -

   > estimate.estimateTableRowList.0.point = 
   >     (estimate.estimateTableRowList.0.totalEffort / 4.5)

---

I have some common cols that I have built into WO_formatted2 from WO_dump2.

Now the above dynamic col set will have to be built into **WO_formatted2 starting Col I** for each WO-1, WO-9 etc, built from WO_dump2.

---

I cannot capture any dynamic col headers, take its cell content, do some calculations & paste under specific cols in WO_formatted2, all being driven by every Col C.Value in WO_formatted2.

Hope I could make my requirement clear.

---

Below is what I use to build the common cols, a working piece of code -

```
Sub ColumnCopy()
'   **** common wo field copy - based on col headers ****
    Dim arrCols
    Dim shtSrc As Worksheet
    Dim rngDest As Range, hdr, pn
    arrCols = Array("estimate.reqType", "estimate.refNumber", 
    "documentInfo.workorderno", _
    "documentInfo.workorderDesc", "documentInfo.currentStatus.value", _
    "documentInfo.woPriority", "documentInfo.woReleaseMonth", _
    "documentInfo.woReleaseYear", "estimate.selectedComplexity")  '<- col   
   headers to copy

   Set shtSrc = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("WO_dump2")
   Set rngDest = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("WO_formatted2").Range("A1")

    'loop over columns
    For Each hdr In arrCols
        pn = Application.Match(hdr, shtSrc.Rows(1), 0)
        If Not IsError(pn) Then
            shtSrc.Range(shtSrc.Cells(1, pn), _
                         shtSrc.Cells(Rows.Count, pn).End(xlUp)).Copy rngDest
        Else
            rngDest.Value = hdr
            rngDest.Interior.Color = vbRed
        End If
        Set rngDest = rngDest.Offset(0, 1)
    Next hdr
End Sub

Sub MainProcessing()

    'declare variables
    Dim src As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
    Dim q As Integer
    Dim lastRow As Long, RowToTest As Long

    Set src = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("WO_dump2")
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("WO_formatted2")

    'filter only "Submitted" status from the main list
    For RowToTest = Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
        With Cells(RowToTest, "E")
            If .Value <> "Submitted" _
            Then _
            Rows(RowToTest).EntireRow.Delete
        End With
    Next RowToTest

    'convert number to month name for a specific range
    For x = 2 To 50000
        If ws.Range("G" & x) <> "" Then
            ws.Range("G" & x) = MonthName(ws.Range("G" & x), True)
            ws.Range("G" & x).Value = ws.Range("G" & x).Value & " " & 
            ws.Range("H" & x)
        End If
    Next x

    'delete the not-required year col after mth-year formatting
    Columns("H:H").Delete

    'insert 5 blank rows after each valid data row
    q = 3
    Do
        Rows(q).Resize(5).Insert
        q = q + 6
    Loop Until IsEmpty(Cells(q, "C"))
End Sub
```

Comment: Could not clearly understand the objective. 1 if intent is to copy each columns from Sheet `WO_dump2` to `WO_formatted2` to according to the header text and create ` new column  with headers.  2. Why `arrCols` used is sheets have their individual headers.  3. Whats the use of user inputs in this context . May pl edit and add screenshot of input and intended output sheets. . May pl ping me using at the rate with username.

Comment: @AhmedAU - 
1. The intent is to copy - X fixed cols & Y dynamic col sets from WO_dump2 to WO_formatted2. Not all cols are to be copied. The code above is to copy the X fixed cols only.

2. I used arrCols since it will search WO_dump2 with col names & not their position.

3. User inputs actually generate the dynamic col sections - different estimate rows for different WO.
WO-1 has 3 sets of dynamic cols - 0.skillSet.skillSetId, 1.skillSet.skillSetId, 2.skillSet.skillSetId & estimate.projOsTotEffort.

WO-22 has 5 sets of dynamic cols - 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, and estimate.projOsTotEffort.